# O que é DelayedExpansion e por que não é habilitada por padrão?

Tags: batch, cmd, ms-dos

Geralmente ao criar um batch que utilize qualquer bloco de de código, como `loops for` ou `if`, acabamos passando por este problema e então descobrimos a necessidade de setar `EnableDelayedExpansion`.

Códigos como este geram erros a cada iteração:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set cont=0
FOR /l %%G in (1,1,5) Do (
    echo [%cont%]
    set /a cont+=1
 )
echo Total = %cont%
```

Saída sem os devidos números incrementados:

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
Total = 5
```

Por que então esta configuração não é habilitada por padrão?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Definição e uso

`DelayedExpansion` faz as variáveis serem "expandidas" (transformadas de nomes de variáveis para valores) durante o *runtime*, isto é, durante a execução do código.

O padrão é que elas sejam "expandidas" durante o *parsing* (antes da execução do código, quando o programa efetivamente *lê* o que você escreveu).

Quando ativado, você pode fazer referência à variáveis usando exclamações (`!nome!`) além do comum, `%nome%`.

---

### Exemplo 1

Vejamos um exemplo delas em ação:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set variavel=primeiro
set variavel=segundo & echo %variavel% !variavel!
```

O código acima pode parecer simples, mas ele representa o efeito do `DelayedExpansion` bem.

Quando o código passa pelo *parser*, a variável `%variavel%` é "expandida" para o valor dela, definido na primeira linha, `"primeiro"`.

Porém, a referência à `variavel` utilizando os pontos de exclamação (`!variavel!`) não é expandida ainda, pois ela está com o *delay* ativado. Quando o código é executado, `variavel` é definida para `"segundo"` e, portanto, altera o valor de `!variavel!`. Assim, temos como output:

```
primeiro segundo
```

---

### Exemplo 2

Vejamos outro exemplo para esclarecer melhor:

```
@echo off

set valor=0
for /l %%G in (1,1,5) do (echo [%valor%] & set /a valor+=1)
echo Total = %valor%
```

Aqui, o loop `for` executa de 1 a 5, indo de 1 em 1. Porém, porque o *parser* já passou pelo código, já houve a substituição de `%valor%` por `0`, mesmo se essa não era nossa intenção. O output fica:

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
Total = 5
```

Porém, nem tudo está perdido! Usando `DelayedExpansion`, podemos contornar esse equívoco:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set valor=0
for /l %%G in (1,1,5) do (echo [!valor!] & set /a valor+=1)
echo Total = %valor%
```

Aqui, `!valor!` está sendo usado e, portanto, ele só será substituido durante a execução do código. Quando o `for` passar por ele, ele é substituido pelo atual valor de `valor` (hehe). Ficamos então com o output que era esperado:

```
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
Total = 5
```

---

### Por que não é habilitado por padrão?

Honestamente, eu não sei. Provavelmente devido a performance e otimização de código. Códigos maiores provavelmente sofreriam um pouco se tivessem que atualizar a cada iteração todas as variáveis enquanto têm outras instruções para realizar.

Mas você pode habilitar por padrão alterando o valor no registro do Windows, caso seja algo que lhe incomode.